# SSL configuration for fedex web service using command line

Tags: java, web-services, ssl

Downloaded the FedEx web service for smartpost shipment and tried to run their sample file and calling the `processShipment` service using command line (Java). I am getting the error as

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: WSWS7130E: No Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) 
>   configuration is available for the ..............

Can someone please help how to do SSL configuration for executing this using command line.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been given a client certificate and truststore to use when connecting to the service?

Typically you can configure SSL for client authentication if you have a keystore and a truststore, configuring them at runtime using the following properties

- javax.net.ssl.keyStore
- javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
- javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
- javax.net.ssl.trustStore
- javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
- javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType

These can be passed in at runtime as follows:

```
java -cp myjar.jar com.test.Main -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=keystore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=letmein -Djavax.net.....
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace in your original question?