# Providing keystore to webService client

Tags: eclipse, web-services, ssl, webservice-client, keystore

Hi I have created a web service client in eclipse from wsdl file. But when I try to access the service from client it says.
No SSL configuration available for the endpoint. And then the address of my endpoint.
Please let me know how can I provide ssl configuration through key store to my webservice client.
I have standalone client and keystore provided by the client.
TIA

Comment: Which technology have you used?

Comment: ibm jdk with jetty server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start by checking whats there in your keystore:

```
keytool -list -keystore D:\Tomcat\ukdp.keystore -storepass 123456
```

A [sample](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ConfiguringSSLSupport) of what your conduit definition might look like:-

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xmlns:http="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration"
  xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/security.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration
      http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/configuration/http-conf.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

  <http:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world}HelloWorld.http-conduit">

    <http:tlsClientParameters>
      <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="password">
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                      file="my/file/dir/Morpit.jks"/>
      </sec:keyManagers>
      <sec:trustManagers>
        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="password"
                      file="my/file/dir/Truststore.jks"/>
      </sec:trustManagers>
      <sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
        <!-- these filters ensure that a ciphersuite with
             export-suitable or null encryption is used,
             but exclude anonymous Diffie-Hellman key change as
             this is vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks -->
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_EXPORT1024_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_DES_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_AES_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:include>.*_WITH_NULL_.*</sec:include>
        <sec:exclude>.*_DH_anon_.*</sec:exclude>
      </sec:cipherSuitesFilter>
    </http:tlsClientParameters>
    <http:authorization>
      <sec:UserName>Betty</sec:UserName>
      <sec:Password>password</sec:Password>
    </http:authorization>
    <http:client AutoRedirect="true" Connection="Keep-Alive"/>

  </http:conduit>

</beans>
```

Also I found some Threads which could help you:-

- [Apache CXF wsdl download via SSL/TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755293/apache-cxf-wsdl-download-via-ssl-tls)
- [Problems accessing a HTTPS Webservice](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014049423)
- [No SSL configuration is available for endpoint](http://garywaddell.com/2011/10/07/wsws3740e-error-no-ssl-configuration-is-available-for-endpoint/)
- [SSL configuration for fedex web service using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9846853/ssl-configuration-for-fedex-web-service-using-command-line)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) and set up the client conduit. Refer to the `Configuring SSL Support` section in [this great tutorial](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html#ClientHTTPTransport%28includingSSLsupport%29-ConfiguringSSLSupport).

Hope this helps.